# Visiting Badlands National Park in November

Tags: weather-and-climate, national-parks, south-dakota

I happened to book a flight to Denver to see a friend. I decided to visit Badlands National Park as it is 6-7 hours drive and I've never been to Great Plains before. As the trip is this weekend, I'm now contemplating if it is alright to visit this place during this time. Is starting November alright or bad time ? Especially considering how windy the place is.

Comment: Look at the online weather forecasts and decide.What weather.com shows for next weekend looks decent for exploring that area.

Comment: This weekend's weather looks really good, and not all that windy either.

Comment: Is it "alright or bad" by what criteria?

Comment: Also, be aware that the Badlands is in no way characteristic of the Great Plains. If you want to experience the Great Plains, drive 7 hours due east, instead, to Salina or Wichita, Kansas. (It's a lot like watching the same 20 minutes of CSPAN on repeat for 7 hours)

Comment: @Flimzy Isn't that mostly farmland?  Very, very little of the pre-European or even pre-human landscape is left.  Maybe Grasslands National Park would do?  But that's at least a 12 hour drive straight  north, according to Google Maps.

Comment: @gerrit: Yes, it's farm land. It's boring. Perhaps the _most_ boring part of the USA. But it's what the great plains are!

Comment: @Flimzy Farmland is what the Great Plains have been turned into by humans, in particular by Europeans.  Virtually all of the original prairie has disappeared (of the Iowa tallgrass prairie, less than 0.1% is left).  Originally the Great Plains were teeming with wildlife, such as millions of buffaloes.  I think it would have been an impressive region to visit.  Although I have yet to go there, as far as I'm aware, Grasslands National Park is the most authentic well-protected area that is left.  And personally, I find Saskatchewan a lot prettier than Toronto.

Comment: @gerrit: It's still impressive to visit, if you're not accustomed to the terrain. It's just repetitive. From what I've read of pre-civilization accounts, it was back then, too.  It just repeated different things.

Comment: @Flimzy Someone told me this week that he got bored by the repetitiveness of arches and canyons in Utah, and I know people who consider that if you have seen one mountain, you've seen all mountains.  So I suppose any landscape on Earth could be considered repetitive.

Comment: @Flimzy It's pretty clear that he's primarily concerned about the weather. But perhaps there are other things as well. Editing the question would be a good idea in this case.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Maybe... but he also says `As the trip is this weekend...` which makes me think he might be concerned with overcrowding or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

November should be fine for visiting Badlands National Park, provided you're prepared for whatever the weather happens to be.

The park is open year-round, though some facilities are only open in the summer, and most events take place only in the summer. But [hiking](http://www.nps.gov/badl/planyourvisit/hiking.htm), [camping](http://www.nps.gov/badl/planyourvisit/camping.htm), and the [in-park hotel](http://cedarpasslodge.com/) are available year round. (For other ideas, see the park's official list of [things to do](http://www.nps.gov/badl/planyourvisit/things2do.htm).)

As for the weather, while [*average* high and low temperatures](http://www.nps.gov/badl/planyourvisit/weather.htm) in November are 10°C and -3°C respectively, weather in the Plains states can vary dramatically. You could find yourself in a 30°C degree heat wave or a -30°C degree blizzard. And it's not unusual for dramatic shifts in weather to be just a few days apart. Check the weather before you go, dress in layers, and bring extra clothing in case it gets colder than predicted.